# Can a python singleton class be inherited?

Tags: python, inheritance, singleton

My idea is any one of the objects should exist for all the subclasses of a Singleton class.
The code that I have been trying and the result matrix is given below. The matrix seems to be working fine in the case of subclasses. Am I going the wrong way? Did it get what happens in the case of a Parent class object and a subclass object?

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(
                                cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

class A(Singleton):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class B(Singleton):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class C(B):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1=Singleton()
    s2=Singleton()
    if(id(s1)==id(s2)):
        print "Same"
    else:
        print "Different"

'''
I got a result matrix for s1 and s2
           |************ s2 **************************|           
s1         |Singleton() |A()      | B()     | C()     |
===========|==========================================|
Singleton()|Same        |Different|Different|Different|
A()        |Different   |Same     |Same     |Same     |
B()        |Different   |Same     |Same     |Same     |
C()        |Different   |Same     |Same     |Same     |
'''
```

Comment: A singleton is inherently equivalent to a global variable, only it obfuscates that fact with extra code that can go subtly wrong. Why not just do `class A(object): ...` then create a global instance immediately after with `a = A()`? You get a single global instance that **looks** like a single global instance, and it's available in exactly the same scope. If lazy initialization is what you want there are ways to achieve that that actually *look* like that's what you're doing.

Comment: If you fix the error where your subclasses don't return anything, you get very strange behaviour. If you do `s1=Singleton()` then `s2=A()` then they'll both be the same object (an instance of `Singleton`), but if you do `s1=A()` then `s2=Singleton()` they'll be different objects (an instance of `A` and an instance of `Singleton` respectively).

Comment: Which means in some distant part of your program `A().method_of_a()` will either work or throw an exception (or inexplicably call a super-class implementation), depending on whether `Singleton` was already instantiated. I cannot imagine how this could be desired behaviour; what do you intend to **do** with this hierarchy of singleton classes?

Comment: This gave me some light. I have been trying to avoid an explicit checking for each subclass whether any instance (global instance) exists for each subclass. Now I think such a check is required for each subclass

Comment: A singleton that can be subclassed is inherently a contradiction in terms. Either you violate the class invariant that makes it a singleton, or you violate LSP.

Answer (score 4):

None of the subclasses' `__new__()` methods have an explicit `return` statement, so they all return `None`. That's why their new instances are all the same. With this code, they'll be the same as `Singleton()` too:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

class A(Singleton):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class B(Singleton):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(B, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

class C(B):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(C, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

It's not even necessary to define `__new__()` for the subclasses:

```
class A(Singleton):
    pass

class B(Singleton):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass
```

Comment: Note that with this code if I ever instantiate a `Singleton` directly, (not through a subclass), then it will set `_instance` on `Singleton`. This means that all further subclasses that get instantiated will find a non-`None` `cls._instance` in their MRO, and will return that instead of creating an instance of themselves.

Comment: I understood that to be the desired behavior.

Comment: I doubt that, though I think the flaw is really in the design, not in your code. I can't think of a plausible situation in which that behaviour would be useful, rather than a bug. I think the poster probably doesn't intend to instantiate `Singleton` directly (or create further subclasses of the `Singleton` subclasses).

Comment: The OP said that the desired behavior was for `id(s1) == id(s2)` and said it was "working fine" when `s1` and `s2` were both subclasses, but not where one was `Singleton` and the other was a subclass. Since the test code includes direct instantiation of `Singleton` it's hard to see how that would not be intended. As far as the design goes, as you point out singleton-enforcing classes are neither necessary nor really a good idea in Python. But I just work here.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. You're quite right, and I wasn't reading close enough. That seems absurd.

Comment: How can this be correctly extended for the case where classes' `__init__` takes arguments? Currently this faills.

Answer (score 3):

The code looks fine but it doesn't make sense to pick one singleton value to be shared for a class and its subclasses.  The whole point of a subclass is to be different in some way from the parent class and from sibling subclasses.  It seems odd to me that each class doesn't have its own distinct singleton instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with help of abstract classes. In my it looks like:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class BasicClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls.instance:
            cls.instance = super(BasicClass, cls).__new__(
                                    cls, *args, **kwargs)

        return cls.instance

    @abstractmethod
    def action(self):
        pass#do smthing


class FirstLevelChild(BasicClass):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def action(self):
        pass#do smthing in this or other abstract method
        # also pearent method can be called with help of super

class SecondLevelChild1(FirstLevelChild):
    def action(self):
        pass#do smthing unique for this class
        # in this or other abstract method
        # also pearent method can be called with help of super

class SecondLevelChild2(FirstLevelChild):
    def action(self):
        pass#do smthing unique for this class
        # in this or other abstract method
        # also pearent method can be called with help of super
```

Lets check

```
>>> a1 = SecondLevelChild1()
>>> a2 = SecondLevelChild1()
>>> b1 = SecondLevelChild2()
>>> b2 = SecondLevelChild2()
>>> a1 == b1
False
>>> a1 ==a2
True
>>> b1 == b2
True
>>>
```

ATTENTION! This solution will help if You need to instantiate only last level child classes. You would not able to instantiate abstract classes.

Comment: Does the `FirstLevelChild` really need to have `ABCMeta` as its metaclass ? And if we remove this I believe the statment `a1 == b1` will become True