# How to write an inheritable Singleton in Python for classes that take arguments upon init?

Tags: python, inheritance, singleton

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8237462/913098), I wrote the following

```
class Singleton(object):
    """
    Inherit this to ensure a single instance of the inheriting class if ever created.
    This also affects classes that inherit the inheriting class, recursively.
    """
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instances.get(cls, None) is None:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        return Singleton._instances[cls]


class A(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.value = value


a1 = A(1)
a2 = A(2)
b1 = B(3)
b2 = B(4)


print(f"1: {a1.value} 2: {a2.value} 3: {b1.value} 4: {b2.value}")
```

Which fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata_thin/uv_metadata_thin/factories/sdfsdf.py", line 15, in <module>
    a1 = A(1)
  File "/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata_thin/uv_metadata_thin/utils/singleton.py", line 10, in __new__
    cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

I expected only the 1st parameters to "catch", meaning output should be

`"1: 1 2: 1 3: 3 4: 3"`

and certainly not fail.

---

How to write an inheritable Singleton whose inheriting classes may define an `__init__` that takes in arguments?

Comment: Read the error message - `object.__new__` only takes one argument, you _also_ pass arbitrary args and kwargs. And `"b3" != "b1"`.

Comment: Again, read the error message - the line it fails on calls `super(Singleton, cls).__new__`, what did you think that was going to do?

Comment: Alright, deleting the `*args` and `**kwargs` solves that. Can you please verify the linked answer is wrong, or explain why they passed `args` there?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What I think is `super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)` evaluates to one level up, all the way through the inheritence tree up to `object`, where it should not be passed `args` and `kwargs`. But I can't verify this very easily, hence asking. Do I need to write it with a stopping condition checking if the class' parent is object? What's the correct way of handling this? Surely, deleting args and kwargs isn't the way

Comment: The linked answer you used, as you've discovered, doesn't work if arguments are passed (it only works when args and kwargs are an empty tuple and an empty dictionary, respectively).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I posted an answer, it may be over-complicated. Would appreciate if you can go over it and maybe see faults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a slight edition of `Singleton`, I was able to create a more flexible version.

```
class DirectInstantiationError(AssertionError):
    pass


class Singleton(object):
    """
    Inherit this to ensure a single instance of the inheriting class if ever created.
    This also affects classes that inherit the inheriting class, recursively.
    """
    _instances = {}
    __called_from_instance = False

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.__called_from_instance:
            raise DirectInstantiationError("Must use .instance(). Don't instantiate directly")
        if cls._instances.get(cls, None) is not None:
            return Singleton._instances[cls]
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        klass = type(self)
        if self._instances.get(klass, None) is None:
            super(Singleton, klass).__init__(klass, *args, **kwargs)
            self._instances[klass] = self

    @classmethod
    def overwrite_instance(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.__called_from_instance = True
        instance = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__called_from_instance = False
        cls._instances[cls] = instance

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls, *args, overwrite=False, **kwargs):
        """
        first time always overwrites
        :param args:
        :param overwrite:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        if overwrite:
            cls.overwrite_instance(*args, **kwargs)

        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls.overwrite_instance(*args, **kwargs)

        return cls._instances[cls]
```

test cases:

```
from singleton import Singleton, DirectInstantiationError
import pytest


class A(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.value = value


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.value = value


class C(B):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.value = value


def test_singleton():
    with pytest.raises(DirectInstantiationError):
        a1 = A("a1")
    a2 = A.instance("a2")
    assert a2.value == "a2"
    a3 = A.instance()
    assert a3.value == "a2"
    a4 = A.instance("a4", overwrite=True)
    assert a4.value == "a4"
    assert a3.value == "a4"
    assert a2.value == "a4"

    with pytest.raises(DirectInstantiationError):
        b1 = B("b1")
    b2 = B.instance("b2", overwrite=True)
    assert b2.value == "b2"

    c1 = C.instance("c1")
    assert c1.value == "c1"
```